# CentOS doesn't work in full screen even after VirtualBox Guest Additions installation

Tags: virtualbox, fullscreen

I've just download [CentOS 7 Minimal](http://isoredirect.centos.org/centos/7/isos/x86_64/CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1810.iso) and install it in VirtualBox.

Then, I've followed [this site](https://www.tecmint.com/install-virtualbox-guest-additions-in-centos-rhel-fedora/) to install VirtualBox Guest Additions in CentOS, unfortunately full screen still doesn't work even after I rebooting CentOS guest OS.

I also don't see any error during installation.

Here are the summary of the installation process.

```
# yum -y install epel-release
# reboot
# yum -y update
# yum install make gcc kernel-headers kernel-devel perl dkms bzip2
# export KERN_DIR=/usr/src/kernels/$(uname -r)
```

From the Virtual machine menu bar, go to Devices => click on Insert Guest Additions CD image to mount the Guest Additions ISO file in your guest OS.

```
# mount -r /dev/cdrom /media
# cd /media/
# ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

Has anyone experiencing the same issue? I don't have this kind of problem in Ubuntu.

Comment: You should reboot after you update and install new kernel-headers, not after installing epel-release. Also, what do you mean by full screen doesn’t work? Do you get an error? Is there no full screen option?

Comment: You had tagged this with both Ubuntu and CentOS (please only use distribution tags when the question is specific to that distribution). Does that mean your host system is Ubuntu?